# Ng-repeat filter on multiple fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that iterates over a document where I want to do a " | filter:search", but want the filter to run on specific fields in the document.

I found a couple examples, that just don't work.

(I have an input field with a model=search)...

The way they say you target specific fields is like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data | filter({first_name:search,last_name:search })">{{x.first_name}} {{x.last_name}}</div>
```

I remember doing something in the past and I think this is close, but not quite.

Any help?

Comment: x in data | filter : {first_name:search,last_name:search } this is the right syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:filterFn">{{obj.name}}</div>
see this is the function : filterFn



 $scope.filterFn = function(elm)
  {
      if($scope.filterlocation[elm.location])
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false; 
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Code goes here
(function(){
  
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['angular.filter']);
  
  myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    var vm= this;
    vm.x = 20;
    
    vm.tableData = [
      {
        first_name: 'Programmer',
        last_name: '21',
      },{
        first_name: 'Abc',
        last_name: 'Xyz'
      },{
        first_name: 'Kunvar',
        last_name: 'Singh'
      },{
        first_name: 'Cnak',
        last_name: '2'
      }
      ];
  })
  
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-filter@0.5.2" data-semver="0.5.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.2/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter your search text" ng-model="vm.searchText" />
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.tableData | filterBy: ['first_name','last_name']: vm.searchText">
       <td>{{row.first_name}}</td>
       <td>{{row.last_name}}</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <p>This will show filter from <b>two columns</b> only(first_name and last_name) . Not from all. Whatever columns you add into filter array they
   will be searched. all columns will be used by default if you use <b>filter: vm.searchText</b></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for a table to search for eachColumn and for all colums in an input all.
Heres the example ->[pnlkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/j807zZLHaTCDD6hR8Y82/)
All can be done in the view.
**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as rchCtrl">


   <div>
      <label>Search</label>
        <input ng-model="searchAll">
      <hr>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>AGE</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input ng-model="searchID">
            </td>
             <td>
              <input ng-model="searchName">
            </td>
             <td>
              <input ng-model="searchAge">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in peoples |filter: {id:searchID, name:searchName, age:searchAge} | filter:searchAll">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.age}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.peoples = [
    {id:1, name:'Kalesi', age:50},
    {id:2, name:'Jon', age:43},
    {id:3, name:'Jonas', age:34},
    {id:4, name:'Sam', age:29},
    {id:5, name:'Samuel', age:50},
    {id:6, name:'Tyrion', age:20}
    ];


});
```